# setTimeout() function not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Can anyone help advise why this `setTimeout()` function is not working? I have tried many version over the net and it is still not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeSlection(frm, proj, tenure, address, postal, cat, parent, estate, latlng, district, state) {
    alert(proj);
    alert('hello im inside makeselection function');

    opener.projectn.value = proj;
    opener.tenure.value = tenure;
    opener.address.value = address;
    opener.postcode.value = postal;
    opener.category.value = parent;     
    opener.category.onchange();

    opener.state.value = state;
    opener.region.value = estate;
    opener.add.value = latlng;
    opener.latlngse.click();

    //setTimeout(function(){alert('hi');},3000);
    setTimeout(function(){ pelay(cat); },5000);
}

function pelay(cate){
    alert(cate);
    opener.category_id.value = cate;
    this.close;
}

</script>
<body>
 Please select project name.
 <form id="fsrm" name="fsrm" action="#">
 <table width="100%">
 <?php
  for($i=0;$i<count($prolists);$i++){
  $row = $prolists[$i];
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" name="nselect<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="nselect<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->project_name ?>" onclick="JavaScript:makeSlection(this.form, document.getElementById('nselect<?php echo $row->id ?>').value, '<?php echo $row->tenure ?>', '<?php echo $row->address ?>', '<?php echo $row->postal_code ?>', '<?php echo $row->cat ?>', '<?php echo $row->parent_id ?>', '<?php echo $row->estate ?>', '<?php echo $row->lat ?>,<?php echo $row->lng ?>', '<?php echo $row->district ?>', '<?php echo $row->state ?>');">Select</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row->project_name ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <?php } ?> 

</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Even when I try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert('hi');},3000);
```

It's also not working.

Just added the body codes to call the javascript.

Comment: Your setTimeout is inside the makeSelection function so it will only set the timeout once the makeSelection function is executed.

Comment: Note that you've called the function `makeSlection` here. Check that it's not a typo.

Comment: Hi andy, yes the function name is correct. it is makeSlection. In fact the script if without the setTimeout works properly. The setTimeout function don't work as i expect.

Comment: Set an alert before `setTimeout function` - to see the control comes over there. Also, I have a hunch something is wrong with `opener.category.onchange();` and `opener.latlngse.click();`

Comment: Hi Ani, I set an alert after opener.category.onchange(); and opener.latlngse.click(); the alert did pop up.

Comment: Dude, seriously, that code makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: @Ani `alert()` is not a valid way to debug JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

It does work. Something else must be going wrong for you.

### Long answer

First of all, mixing HTML/Javascript/PHP like that makes it a lot harder for anyone to understand what the hell your code is trying to achive.

Secondly, your question stands a better chance of getting an answer that will help you progress to a solution if you make it [Short, Self Contained, Correct, and add an Example](http://sscce.org/).
Preferably one we can view online which demonstrates the simplest version you could create that is working (or in this case broken).

Such a version would look something like this:

```
<script>
function makeSlection(cat) {
    alert('hello im inside makeselection function');
    setTimeout(function(){ pelay(cat); },1500);
}

function pelay(cate){
    alert(cate);
}
</script>

<button onclick="JavaScript:makeSlection('foo');">Select</button>
```

I took the liberty of creating [an example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/potherca/KY7pK/) from the code you provided us with.

Which leads me to the third point: the simplified version of the code you gave us in your question works. Both alerts get triggered.

So I'm guessing we are not getting the full picture here.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setTimeout` is inside the `makeSelection` function so it will only set the timeout once the `makeSelection` function is executed.

Comment: sorry any idea how i should do it? i am not sure, I actually see other samples over the net doing it this way.

Comment: I need the top lines to complete before setTimeout executes.

Comment: Hi Andy, it is something like that <button type="submit" name="nselect<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="nselect<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->project_name ?>" onclick="JavaScript:makeSlection(this.form, document.getElementById('nselect<?php echo $row->id ?>').value, '<?php echo $row->tenure ?>', '<?php echo $row->address ?>', '<?php echo $row->postal_code ?>', '<?php echo $row->cat ?>', '<?php echo $row->parent_id ?>', '<?php echo $row->estate ?>', '<?php echo $row->lat ?>,<?php echo $row->lng ?>', '<?php echo $row->district ?>', '<?php echo $row->state ?>');">Select</button>

Comment: @user3126531 Please edit and paste the code to your question instead of here.